# How do I report the results for a test that matches ID's across different sources?

Tags: sql, vertica

An ID can exist in multiple SOURCE's. I need to test whether the VALUE for the same ID matches across different SOURCES. If they didn't all match across all sources, it should return FALSE.

```
CREATE TABLE example_table
(
    SOURCE varchar(255),  
    ID varchar(255),
    VALUE varchar(255)
);

INSERT INTO example_table (SOURCE, ID, VALUE)
VALUES ('A', 1, 55), ('A', 2, 36), ('B', 1, 55), ('B', 2, 34);
```

With the code above, I would like the query to return the following:

```
ID    MATCH
1     TRUE
2     FALSE
```

This is a bit of a "big data" problem, as there are millions of ID's and around 50 or so sources. The query is being written for Vertica 9.2.

Comment: In your question you mentioned value for same id, so you need to modify the expected output by including value column as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can use aggregation:

```
select et.id,
       (case when min(value) = max(value) then 'true' else 'false' end) as match
from example_table et
group by et.id;
```

You can simplify this to:

```
select et.id,
       (min(value) = max(value)) as match
from example_table et
group by et.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Using **SELF JOIN** and **GROUP BY**, you can write the query as below:

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.value, (CASE WHEN t1.value = t2.value THEN 'true' ELSE 'false' END) AS 'MATCH'
FROM example_table t1 INNER JOIN example_table t2
ON t1.id = t2.id
WHERE t1.source != t2.source
GROUP BY t1.id, t1.value;
```

**Output:**

```
id | value | match
1    55      true
2    34      false
2    36      false
```